# Обработка ошибки загрузки через Composer

Tags: php, autoload, composer

Использую Composer для автозагрузки своих классов.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

В случае если не был найден файл из которого загружать класс сервер уходит в 500 ошибку.

Пробовал оборачивать в try catch, блок try нормально обрабатывается, но если файл не найден опять 500я.

Использую Webmatrix со всеми вытекающими.

php 5.4

Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? Есть решение?

Предложения сменить среду разработки не принимаются.

Comment: в логе то что на тему 500 ошибки ? включите display_errors

Comment: Fatal error: Class '***' not found

Webmatrix3 установил все починилось)

Самое неприятное что ошибка в строке, которая заключена в try

Comment: пришлось ограничить возможность автозагрузки, однако только в одном месте кода, в другом может найтись место для ошибки, поэтому вопрос все еще актуален.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php не отлавливает фатальные ошибки через try/catch, 
"Class not found" это фатальная ошибка, вам нужно использовать
[class_exists('classname',true)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.class-exists.php)
прежде чем инициализировать класс.

по мотивам [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421332/815386)

---

специально для вас с использованием Composer:

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
if (class_exists('Monolog\Logger',true)) {
        $log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
        echo "Log good\n";
}
if (class_exists('Foo\Bar',true)) {
        $test = new Foo\Bar('test');
        echo "test good\n";
} else {
        echo "test bad\n";
}
//$test = new Foo\Bar('param'); //Fatal ERROR!
```

Выдает

```
Log good
test bad
```

Comment: Боюсь это невозможно, я использую Composer как автозагрузчик, т.е. класса изначально не существует в контексте, следовательно проверка на class exists невозможна. 

Нашел временное решение подгружать только заведомо имеющиеся файлы классов, однако это костыль.

Может быть есть какой то ключ для сборки Composer'a, чтобы он возвращал Exception в случае если не находит класса.

В принципе можно немного его модифицировать, но это было бы нежелательно.

Comment: Я так понимаю вы не особо разбираетесь в вопросе, поэтому дам ссылки для изучения, лишними эти знания не будут:

Composer

http://getcomposer.org/ habrahabr.ru/post/145946/‎

spl_autoload

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

Comment: Я же говорю, если автолоадер, то true во второй параметр. exeption после new выдавать невозможно, т.к. это необрабатываемая ошибка, наверное можно в автолоадере exit сделать, что тоже ни к чему хорошему не приведет.(как вариант можно сделать eval класса, в конструкторе которого выдавать expetion, только зачем это, если есть class_exists)

Comment: С тестом стало понятнее, не смотрел описание функции, поэтому к сожалению не знал о наличии ключа.

Получается что он во время теста обьявляет класс?